# Is it possible to share a Tensorflow model among Gunicorn workers?

Tags: api, tensorflow, keras, webserver, production

I need to put in production a Tensorflow model with a simple APIs endpoint. The model should be shared among processes/workers/threads in order to not waste too many resources in terms of memory.

I already tried with multiple gunicorn workers setting the --preload option and loading the model before the definition of the resources, but after a while I get timeout error. The model is not responding. I know that there is Tensorflow serving service available for this purpose, but the problem is about the fact that the model is not still available at deployment time and the ML pipeline is composed of many different components (the Tensorflow model is just one of these components). The end user (customer) is the one that trains/saves the model. (I am using docker) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the Tensorflow runtime and global state is not fork safe.
See this thread: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5448 or this one: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/51832
You could attempt to load the model only in the workers using the `post_fork` and `post_worker_init` server hooks.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32293144)